# When/how do I know response is NOT redirect in ZF1 and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework, redirect

I expect this question is too vague to be answerable as phrased in the title, so I'm expanding it to explain what I'm really trying to accomplish.

What I meant by the title question is: I'm in a ZF1 MVC application processing a request, and I want to find out if my response is NOT to redirect (and similarly for a WordPress request). Kind of doesn't make sense without a crystal ball.

**This is what I'm trying to do that made me phrase the question that way**

My ZF1 MVC application requires users to register and login, and it incorporates WordPress functionality such that a logged-in MVC user is automatically logged-in as a corresponding WordPress user. In general, one user cannot see another user's data unless there is some relationship between the users (a la facebook friends) or unless the user owning the data has marked it publicly visible.

I want to implement a button that a user can press to say "show me the current page the way someone else would see it".

My initial/current thought was to go into the class holding the logged-in identity and add a notion of *temporary viewing identity*. My button would then set the *temporary viewing identity*, and redirect to the current url. The class holding the logged-in identity would simply report the *temporary viewing identity*, if it was set, as the logged-in identity. And presto, the user would see the current page as a different user would see it :-). But then the issue becomes how to unset the *temporary viewing identity*.

My thought was that I would unset the *temporary viewing identity* whenever displaying the "final result" of a request, which to me meant whenever I can determine that my response is not a redirect. That's how I arrived at the question.

I'm hoping that someone can either point me at the way to answer my question, or point me at a different/better approach to accomplishing what I'm trying to do. Left to my own devices, I'm thinking along these lines, and I'm not entirely sure of the assumptions I'm making.

1. Every request gets a response, the response starts with headers, and the first header will indicate whether or not there's a redirect.
2. Search the sources of ZF1 and WordPress to find all calls to header().
3. At each such call, add a call to headers_list, and check the first header. If it doesn't specify a redirect, then unset any *temporary viewing identity*

Sounds fairly awful, but perhaps not totally crazy. I'd love to be steered in a better direction!

**EDIT 1:**
Hmm, looks like calling header_register_callback() during bootstrap would avoid the need to track down occurrences of calls to header() in the sources. The callback function could call headers_list() to see if there's a redirect, and if not, clear the *temporary viewing identity*

**EDIT 2:**
Incorporating the comment from @DanFromGermany
To process the array returned by headers_list() to determine efficiently and reliably whether or not there's a redirection I'd do something like:

```
$redirect = false;
foreach(headers_list() as $header) {
    if (0 === stripos($header, 'location')) {
        // Skip whitespace and verify ":" is next
        $colon = ltrim(substr($header, strlen('location')), " \t");
        if ($colon[0] == ':') {
            $redirect = true;
            break;
        }
}
if (! $redirect) {
    clear_temporary_identity();
}
```

**EDIT 3:**
Unfortunately, I just noticed that header_register_callback() was introduced in PHP 5.4, and I'm stuck at PHP 5.3 (because I want a properly-working APC with Apache mod-PHP, and as far as I can tell I can't get that combo after 5.3.1, as in XAMPP 1.7.3). So now I'm back to searching for calls to header() in the source, and trying to backtrack to places in the source where I could add code to check for redirect. I guess I could simplify a bit by searching for "redirect", but I know I've occasionally seen code that explicitly calls header("Location:...") and exits. So besides a different approach altogether, I'm back to looking for the best way to determine if a response is going to redirect...

**EDIT 4**
For the ZF1 MVC application, I'm thinking that instead of searching through code to find paths that don't redirect, maybe I could just add the call to clear_temporary_identity() to the page layouts. If a request is going to redirect, it isn't going to generate the page layout first (I don't think!). That would sure simplify things. But for WordPress, I'm really not sure, I don't understand its control-flow at all, with html interspersed with php code seemingly willy-nilly. I'll have to search for redirects there to see if I can find some pattern.

Comment: Put a variable in the session before redirecting `isRedirect` and check for that content. Btw the header is not neccessarily in `[0]`. Use `stripos()` with a `foreach`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, what I'm calling the *temporary viewing identity* is stored in the session (along with the real logged-in user identity). I had only ever observed Location headers as coming first, but you're quite right about needing a loop - in the meantime I found http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2. If you were to make this an answer instead of a comment, I'll accept it (unless someone comes along with a better approach). I think the problem is not too unusual, so I'm sure lots of people have real life experience solving it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question you want users to be able to view just one page as another user. Personally I wouldn't try and do anything crazy with redirects - you're asking for trouble there.

Why not simply link to the relevant page and add a query string variable like `?userOverride=123` to it? Then in your user authentication code, if that variable is present, and if the user can view the page as the specified user (i.e. they are 'friends', or however you want to limit it), you use that user as the temporary viewing identity. Clicking on any link on the page would automatically return them to their account (as the query string wouldn't be present). You could also add a box (or top bar) to the page if the temporary viewing identity was used which includes a "Return to your account" link.

If you don't like having it in the query string you could store it in the session instead.

Comment: I certainly don't **want** to do anything crazy with redirects, but the nature of the application (and WordPress, too, I believe) is that constructing a response to the url for the current page **may** involve redirection. I did at first consider adding a query string parameter, but persisting that through redirects is then a pain, and  even just adding code to every controller to check for it isn't so great. Adding a temporary field to the identity solves the persistence problem through the session.

Comment: Letting the class that provides the current identity return the temporary value avoids adding code to every controller. The biggest problem with it is identifying up front every controller where using the temporary identity would leak information - e.g. viewing the current user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

To check wether the site was requested after a redirect attempt,

You could put a variable in the session before redirecting `isRedirect` and check for that content.

The header is not neccessarily in `[0]`, it can also be in `[1]` etc.

I'd rewrite your if like:

```
$headers = headers_list();
foreach ($headers as $header) {
if (stripos('Location:', $header) !== false) {
    clear_temporary_viewing_identity();
}
```

The `Location` header is only sent **to the client**. So I wonder why you don't use `curl` which provides you with all available information without having to parse anything.

The `Location` header **is not sent** **to the server**. You should use a session variable to check in that case. Example:

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['isRedirect'] = true;

header('Location: other.php');
exit;
```

**other.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['isRedirect']) && $_SESSION['isRedirect'] === true) {
    echo 'I came here by a redirect';
}
else {
    echo 'no redirect happened!';
}
```

Comment: I added another edit while you were posting. But now I see you're looking at this a bit differently. Your code uses the session to determine whether or not the request being processed was initiated by a redirect. But I think what I need to know is whether the request being processed will result in a redirect. I want to put a link in the header of every page that causes that page to be displayed as seen by another user. So it goes to a controller passing the current url as a parameter. That controller sets a temporary user id in the session, and redirects to the url passed in.

Comment: @snootsnoot Oh ok, sorry I did misunderstand that ;S

Comment: When that request to the passed-in url is processed, it will behave as if the logged in user is the temporary user, and that processing could (I think) include further redirection in order to reach the final page displayed. So I want to know when I'm processing that final page request (and not some intermediate redirected request) so that I can clear the temporary user information. I don't see how to use the kind of code you've provided to accomplish that goal (of knowing if I should clear the temporary identity).  Oops, collision, I type slowly :-)